# How can I use emacs-jedi with another virtualenv for my project?

Tags: emacs-jedi

I've installed emacs-jedi several months ago and it worked very well. After some time without a python project I came back (with an update to emacs 26 and re-installed emacs-jedi) and I have a problem:

When I just start emacs, jedi works fine. But as soon as I run `M-x pyvenv-workon some_python3_venv`, jedi stops working. I get the dreaded error (and of course I tried to `jedi:install-server`) :

```
Error (jedi):
================================
Failed to start Jedi EPC server.
================================

*** EPC Error ***
Server may raise an error. Use "M-x epc:pop-to-last-server-process-buffer RET" to see full traceback:
No handlers could be found for logger "jediepcserver"


*** EPC Server Output (last 10 lines) ***
No handlers could be found for logger "jediepcserver"


*** EPC Server Config ***
Server arguments: ("/home/me/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/jediepcserver" "--virtual-env" "/home/me/.virtualenvs/some_project")
Actual command: /home/me/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/jediepcserver
VIRTUAL_ENV envvar: "/home/me/.virtualenvs/some_project"

*** jedi-mode is disabled in #<buffer algorithms.py> ***
Fix the problem and re-enable it.

*** You may need to run "M-x jedi:install-server". ***
This could solve the problem especially if you haven't run the command yet
since Jedi.el installation or update and if the server complains about
Python module imports.
```

In the "good after fresh start" case, `jedi:show-setup-info` tells me this:

```
;; Emacs Lisp version:
(:emacs-version "26.1" :jedi-version "0.2.7" :python-environment-version "0.0.2alpha0")
;; Python version:
((:version "2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) \n[GCC 8.3.0]" :name "sys" :file nil)
 (:version "0.13.3" :name "jedi" :file "/home/me/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jedi/__init__.pyc")
 (:version "0.0.5" :name "epc" :file "/home/me/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/epc/__init__.pyc")
 (:version "0.0.3" :name "sexpdata" :file "/home/me/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sexpdata.pyc"))
;; Command line:
(:virtualenv "/usr/bin/virtualenv" :virtualenv-version "15.1.0\n")
;; Customization:
((jedi:complete-on-dot)
 (jedi:doc-display-buffer . display-buffer)
 (jedi:doc-hook view-mode)
 (jedi:doc-mode . rst-mode)
 (jedi:environment-root)
 (jedi:environment-virtualenv)
 (jedi:get-in-function-call-delay . 1000)
 (jedi:get-in-function-call-timeout . 3000)
 (jedi:goto-definition-config
  (nil nil nil)
  (t nil nil)
  (nil definition nil)
  (t definition nil)
  (nil nil t)
  (t nil t)
  (nil definition t)
  (t definition t))
 (jedi:goto-definition-marker-ring-length . 16)
 (jedi:imenu-create-index-function . jedi:create-nested-imenu-index)
 (jedi:import-python-el-settings . t)
 (jedi:install-imenu)
 (jedi:install-python-jedi-dev-command "pip" "install" "--upgrade" "git+https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi.git@master#egg=jedi")
 (jedi:key-complete .
                    [C-tab])
 (jedi:key-goto-definition .
                           [67108910])
 (jedi:key-goto-definition-pop-marker .
                                      [67108908])
 (jedi:key-related-names . "r")
 (jedi:key-show-doc . "d")
 (jedi:server-args)
 (jedi:server-command "/home/me/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/jediepcserver")
 (jedi:setup-keys)
 (jedi:tooltip-method)
 (jedi:use-shortcuts)
 (python-environment-default-root-name . "default")
 (python-environment-directory . "~/.emacs.d/.python-environments")
 (python-environment-virtualenv "virtualenv" "--system-site-packages" "--quiet"))
```

After I ran `M-x pyvenv-workon`, I get almost the same output, but the section `;; Python version:` shows some error:

```
;; Emacs Lisp version:
(:emacs-version "26.1" :jedi-version "0.2.7" :python-environment-version "0.0.2alpha0")
;; Python version:
nil
;; EPC error:
(:get-epc-error
 (wrong-type-argument epc:manager nil))
```

What Do I have to do to run emacs-jedi together with the virtualenv that I need for my project? I tried to customize `jedi:server-args`, but that didn't help.